# Jenkins declarative pipeline with separate docker images for a whole pipeline and some stage(s)

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

It's possible to provide different `docker` images for different `jenkins` stages, but is it possible to provide some default `docker` image for a whole pipeline while providing some specific `docker` image for some stage(s)?

For example (it's possible):

```
pipeline {
  agent none

  stages {
    stage('first stage') {
      agent {
        docker { image 'first_docker' }
      }
      steps {
        sh 'echo "just do it"'
      }
    }
    stage('second stage') {
      agent {
        docker { image 'second_docker' }
      }
      steps {
        sh 'echo "did it"'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The question is about:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker { image 'default_docker' }
  }

  stages {
    stage('first stage') {
      steps {
        sh 'echo "just do it"'
      }
    }
    stage('second stage') {
      agent {
        docker { image 'second_docker' }
      }
      steps {
        sh 'echo "did it"'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I don't mean a case where a default `docker` image has a `docker` inside and thus providing 'Matryoshka' (a nested doll).

Comment: To the best of my knowledge and according to the documentation, it is not possible to do this by intrinsic/native means. If someone has a workaround then that would be awesome.